# Buffer.byteLength vs file size

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, buffer, express-fileupload

I have a file that is roughly 51Mb (as seen in Finder). "GetInfo" shows `Size: 51,534,849 bytes (52.3 MB on disk)`

[image]

When I upload this file to the server the `byteLength` of the uploaded `Buffer` is a lot smaller. Does it depend on the file type or any other properties? How do I get the correct uploaded file size

```js
    import { UploadedFile } from "express-fileupload";

    private getFileSize(fileUpload: UploadedFile) {
        const fileData = fileUpload.data;
        console.log(fileData.byteLength, fileData.length, Buffer.byteLength(fileData))
        return fileData.???;
    }
```

In the above `fileData.byteLength`, `fileData.length`, `Buffer.byteLength(fileData)` all give the same result of `18118252`, which divided by `1024` is roughly `17Mb`

I am using Postman, if it matters

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload) of **express-fileupload** there is a field on the fileUpload object that's named **size** which should return you the size of the file in bytes.

```
import { UploadedFile } from "express-fileupload";

private getFileSize(fileUpload: UploadedFile) {
    const fileData = fileUpload.data;
    const fileSize = fileUpload.size;
    return fileData.???;
}
```

Regarding the misleading buffer size, not sure why that is. Typically when receiving files, they come in chunks that have to be asynchronously collected before concating the chunks into the file. I assume that the package **express-fileupload** does that for you. Try saving the file to the disk and have a look at the file size and see if it's the same as before the upload.

Comment: the size property on uploaded file object is exactly the same as the `byteLength`. However, I have tried a different file (which is a different type and also a lot smaller just 12 kB) and that one shows the `byteLength` and the `size` property roughly the same as what is seen in the Finder (12232). Could this be because the initial file is an application type file? Or maybe because it's large?